# Plot the Share of one Category of a Categorical Variable with Respect to all Categories of a Second Variable

Tags: r, ggplot2, categorical-data

I have a dataframe like this:

```
df <- data.frame(Reason = sample(rep(c("R1", "R2", "R3", "R4"), each = 100)),
                 Answer = sample(rep(c("yes", "no", "no", "no"), 100)))

head(df)
```

I want ggplot to do a bar plot that shows the share of "yes"-answers (y-axis) for every reason (x-axis).

I tried this:

```
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = interaction(Reason, Answer))) + 
 geom_bar(aes(y = ..count../sum(..count..)))
```

This leads to the following outcome:

[how it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lEcXU.png)

The problem is that the bars sum up to 1 (in total). I want them to sum up to one within each Reason-category. (R1.no and R1.yes should sum up to 1, R2.no and R2.yes should sum up to one and so on).

When this is done, I want to discard all bars bearing information about the "no"-answers. So basically, I just want the shares of the "yes"-answers within each Reason-category. This should look something like that:

[how it should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2h5RF.png)

I obtained the desired result doing this:

```
a <- prop.table(table(df$Reason, df$Answer),1)

df2 <- data.frame(Reason = rownames(as.matrix(a)),
                  share = as.matrix(a)[,2])

ggplot(data = df2, aes(x = reorder(Reason, share), y = share)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
  ylab("share of yes-answers")
```

Can I avoid this work-around and directly get the desired result from ggplot? This would have some major advantages for me.

Thanks alot,
Andi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution by Yuriy only works when it sums up to 100. I think you have to calculate the proportion somehow, otherwise you cannot sort before hand. So in the first part, I manipulate the data by adding a column p, 1 if yes 0 if no.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(99)
df <- data.frame(
Reason = sample(rep(c("R1", "R2", "R3", "R4"), each = 100)),
Answer = sample(rep(c("yes", "no", "no", "no"), 100)))

head(df %>% mutate(p=as.numeric(Answer=="yes")),3)
  Reason Answer p
1     R3     no 0
2     R3    yes 1
3     R1     no 0
```

Then we plot with this data frame, and the y axis is simply the mean of each group on the x-axis, and we can use `stat_summary` with `fun.y=mean`. Now `reorder` works very well in this case because it calculates the averages of each category and reorders according to that:

```
ggplot(df %>% mutate(p=as.numeric(Answer=="yes")),
aes(x=reorder(Reason,p),y=p)) +
 stat_summary(fun.y="mean",geom="bar",fill="orchid4")
```

[image]

And this will work for situations when you have different number of observations for different categories:

```
set.seed(100)
df <- data.frame(
Reason = rep(c("R1", "R2", "R3", "R4"),times=seq(50,200,length.out=4)),
Answer = sample(c("yes","no"),500,prob=c(0.5,0.5),replace=TRUE)
)
# we expect
sort(tapply(df$Answer=="yes",df$Reason,mean))
R2    R4    R3    R1 
0.460 0.505 0.520 0.540 

ggplot(df %>% mutate(p=as.numeric(Answer=="yes")),
    aes(x=reorder(Reason,p),y=p)) +
     stat_summary(fun.y="mean",geom="bar",fill="orange")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, worked out very well for me. One brief remark: When I run your code, the orange plot is 100% reproduced (the one you set seed to 100). The purple plot looks different though (the one you set seed to 99). Maybe you produced the purple plot before you actually ran "set.seed(99)"?

Comment: Hi @AndiLope, glad it worked for you. Thanks for checking it, I reran the code on a PC now, and could get the same plot. Which R version are you on? I am on 3.6.1

Comment: Hi @StupidWolf. I am on R-3.5.1. (Windows 10)

Comment: Yeah, the seed changes from 3.5.1 to 3.6.1, sorry I should have mentioned my R version, or dput the data :)

Comment: Ah, good to now. Funny it stays the same for set.seed(100). No worries, thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

```
ggplot(df[df$Answer == "yes", ]) + 
  geom_bar(aes(x = Reason, y = sort(..prop..), group = 1))
```

Comment: You should add an explanation, code only answers are frowned upon.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, though I'm not really sure what your code does. It does not lead to the same results as @StupidWolfs solution, which reproduces my work-around results perfectly.